# Highlighting in multiValued fields. Also sorting them after search query

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a problem with Solr getting highlighting to work properly.

My schema is a basic one:

- FileName : String
- FileURI : String
- keyValues : String MULTIVALUED

My "keyValues" field can sometime contains a large amount of numbers, up towards 1000.

The real question is, how do I search for a value (with wildcards), in the keyValues field, and "sorting" the result of hits in keyValues, to be at the top of the result?

Say I was going to search for `keyValues:*54*`...
Now instead of getting the result, containing a document, with 1000 keyValues, and the hit `*54*` somewhere in keyValues, finding the value with Ctrl+F or something else. I would like to just put the hits up top in the multiValued field. Is this even possible?

Also, I haven't gotten highlighting to work with my multiValued field at all. My search parameters look like this:

```
http://solr:8080/solr/file-search/select?q=keyValues%3A*54*&hl.fl=keyValues&hl.simple.pre=%3Cb%3E&hl.simple.post=%3C%2Fb%3E&hl.usePhraseHighlighter=true&hl.highlightMultiTerm=true&hl.fragsize=1000000&hl.preserveMulti=true&hl.snippets=100&hl.mergeContiguous=true
```

Any idea how to get it working? If not, is there a way to just extract the highlighted matches from a multiValued field? (I could do it in the frontend, but it'd be much prettier if it was done server-sided)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Got it! 
The problem was that my `keyValues` field was type `String`. I changed to `text_general` and highlighting works.